# Bitmap from String

Tags: java, android, string, bitmap

Is there a way or How do I take a String and create a bitmap from it using Java for development for Android?

I had a look at the java api for bitmaps and couldnt find anything

Comment: what do you mean by string? Are you talking about something like a base64 encode string?

Comment: just Test, a character array. I just need to create a bitmap that is 96 x 96 px big

Comment: You can create a bitmap and set pixel values from any source, including a string. How to do that depends entirely on what's in the string and what you want it to mean. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the decodebytearray method of bitmap factory like

```
byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(myImageData.getBytes());
Bitmap bp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length);
```

Where myImageData is a base64 string.

If you have an array just pass that to the decodeByteArray method.

Answer (score 0):

DrawText on canvas by creating bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your image data is in a String called myImageData, the following should do the trick:

```
byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(myImageData.getBytes());
ImageView image = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
image.setImageBitmap(
        BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length)
);
```

For Base64 decoding, you can use http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/ as Android doesn't contain Base64-support prior to 2.2.

Note, I didn't actually run this code, so you'll have to doublecheck for errors.

more link:
using canvas
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html

Comment: You could have just pointed here instead of copying it verbatim: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801760/android-code-to-convert-base64-string-to-bitmap