# How to convert a Base64 blob string into image in android?

Tags: java, android, image, web, base64

I am receiving a Base64 blob response from my web service. I want to create one image and set it to Imageview in my activity. Here's the code snippet.
Apologies for pasting response.

bs64img - Base64 string response
code -

```
byte[] imageBytes=Base64.decode(bs64img, Base64.DEFAULT);
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes);
Bitmap image=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
ImageView i=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
i.setImageBitmap(image);
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: You didn't have to post the response here, rather should've posted the code snippet of what you'd tried to convert it into an `Image`.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3801881/1168654

Comment: @jaa-c -> I used code on that link . Got this error                     --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
byte[] imgBytesData = android.util.Base64.decode(yourBase64String);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgBytesData, 0, imgBytesData.length);
... then setting your ImageView or saving on FileSystem or ...
```

Comment: Got this error --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null –

Answer (score 0):

In general, embedded images are given as

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg...">
```

That is, all bytes of the file are given. So try:

```
byte[] imageBytes=Base64.decode(bs64img, Base64.DEFAULT);
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes);
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(is);
```